# Cascades signal not working

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-cascades

I have a sheet declared in my QML file, which has the id "splashscreen"

When my app performs a computationally intensive task, I emit the working() signal.

I have this code attached to the main element of my QML file:

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    _encryptedattachment.finished.connect(splashscreen.close);
    _encryptedattachment.working.connect(splashscreen.open);
    console.log("connected");
}
```

If I open the app through an invoke on a file which needs decrypting, the

```
    _encryptedattachment.working.connect(splashscreen.open);
```

does not open the splashscreen, even though the event is being fired (I checked in the debugger that the code

```
emit working()
```

is executed.

EDIT:

I changed the onCreated code to this:

```
onCreationCompleted: {
    splashscreen.open();
    _encryptedattachment.working.connect(showSplash);
    _encryptedattachment.finished.connect(hideSplash);
    console.log("connected");
}
function showSplash() {
    console.log("open splashscreen");
    splashscreen.open();
}
function hideSplash() {
    console.log("close splashscreen");
    splashscreen.close();
}
```

and both those logs are appearing in the console.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that `_encryptedattachment.working.connect(showSplash);` returned true? are you sure that showSplash is not called? If showSplash is called do you call `QApplication::processEvents` after calling show on QSplashScreen instance?

Comment: QApplication::processEvents solved the problem. Thanks. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `QSplashScreen::show()` you must call `QApplication::processEvents()` so eventloop will draw it on screen. Remember to call `QApplication::processEvents()` after each splash screen update.